# How to understand essence of mind (Thought) is consciousness in vedanta?

Tags: mind

i need simple logic to understand mind (each and every thought) is nothing but consciousness. In waking and dreaming state thought are coming and going but i the consciousness is not changing. But how to understand essence of changing thought 
is changeless consciousness.

Comment: You have answered your own question.

Comment: It is believed : THAT which perceives the change is changeless pure consciousness.